# Compare method's runtime performance in slightly different dll's

Tags: c++, performance, dll, compare

I have several builds of a particular dll. The builds only differ in performance enhancements which I would like to measure and compare against eachother, speed initially. I'm looking for a simple pattern to include these .dll's in one project and compare their performance. The dll filename does not reflect the version number, but that could be changed if needed.

How would you do this - using c++ in VS2015?

--
Edit: I have now a project referencing a .lib per .dll (ie lib1->dll1, lib2->dll2, lib3->dll3, etc), each referencing only the corresponding dll. I would assume that the class in the .lib file would call only the referenced .dll but it seems that since the .dll's use the same namespace, that the libs could call any of the .dll's, ie lib2 referencing dll2 could call dll1. There are several mentions about this behaviour on the net, and I can reproduce this. Changing the namespace solves this, but it is not an option to recompile all previous .dll's with unique namespaces. Does anyone know if linking the .dll programatically could solve this?

Comment: I would build one executable per dll, but maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is for a real-time application where the results from the different dll versions must be rendered in 3D side by side. Would work fine if it were to be offline but alas it is not.

Comment: In this case you may be able to use LoadLibrary at runtime, as if you were designing a plugin system. This will definitely complicate the client code, but you should not have to change the individual DLLs.

Comment: That's probably the way to go. I would have prefered a msvc drag'n drop setup, but my current solution isn't less work than programatically getting hold of the different dll's.

Comment: That's the problem with wizards and drag and drop: they do make some supported scenarios simpler to set up, but otherwise you're on your own :)